# Is there any security risk using <noscript>?

Tags: javascript, security

Codes below are two search box that work when javascript is enabled / disabled respectively. It works fine but I'd like to know if there are any security issues, I am validating both forms. I just want to know if `<noscript>` has any security issues in itself.

```
<div class='searchbox1'>
  <form action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter keyword ..." />
    <input type="image" src="./img/search-icon.png" alt="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
<noscript>
  <style>
    .searchbox1 {
        display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <div class='searchbox2'>
      <form action="different.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter keyword ..." />
          <input type="image" src="./img/search-icon.png" alt="submit" />
      </form>
  </div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Why would your server process the same form differently based on whether client-side JS was enabled or not?  The original premise here seems a bit hidden and perhaps flawed which makes it seem like we're being asked to answer a question about a particular tree when we can't see the bigger picture of the forest to know what's really going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

noscript tags just show if there's no JS turned on. **There are no security issues specific to noscript**. Note that I'm not analyzing the security of your actual code, just answering the specific question about noscript security.

I'd also point out that your finishing `</style>` tag is malformed *(note: this has since been fixed in the question code)*. That will give you issues.

I'd also point out that there's a simpler way to do it considering your markup between the two is almost identical except for which PHP file it uses and the class name of the div.

Just use the markup that assumes no JS, and then replace those 2 bits of data **using** JS. That way when there's no JS it has the proper markup for that, when there is JS the JS makes the proper markup for the JS version, and there's only one form in the markup for you to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

> There are no security issues with that whatsoever.

Having that said, something else in this approach is catching my eye. It seems like the only validation you're doing is on the **clientside**. Javascript is completely clientsided, thus can be disabled if the client wishes to do so (which could or could not trigger the `<noscript>`, up to the client's choice) and if you are not validating the information on the **serverside** as well, consider your input in the client's complete control - and in most cases, that's very problematic, because it could raise input based vulnerabilities such as [injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).